# How do I reference the other object in django models

Tags: django

first post here.In Django, I want to have many files be associated with a particular model, so I'm doing a seperate model called files and have model 'A' 'have many' files. But I want my files to be saved in director named by model 'A'. So For example I want something like this:

```
class Show(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField()
     showfolder = models.FilePathField()

class Episode(models.Model):
     show = models.ForeignKey(Show)
     name = models.CharField()
     files = models.ManyToManyField(mp3)

class Mp3(models.Model):
     file = FileField(upload_to=Episode.show.showfolder)
```

So hopefully that last line expresses what I WANT it to do(get the folder name from Show object associated with the episode). The question is how would I really write that?(besides jumping through hoops in the controller.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your current model because of Episode ManyToMany relation to Mp3 it is possible for one file to be associated with one or more episodes. That would mean that your file will have to simultaneously exist in several locations.

To have a hierarchical structure you need ForeignKey to Episode in Mp3 model:

```
class Mp3(Model):
     episode = ForeignKey(Episode)
```

Now about your file name. According to [django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield), `upload_to` attribute can accept callable and will pass two arguments to it: `instance` and `filename`.

```
def get_file_name(instance, original_filename):
    return os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, 'mp3', instance.episode.show.showfolder,     
                        original_filename)

class Mp3(Model):
     file = FileField(upload_to=get_file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks Skirmantas! After reading your answer I clicked on your link and it turns out that right before posting I had read everything up to the sentence I needed to know and somehow skipped it!(I usually never skim, too). As for a file being in more than one place, I don't think I have to worry about that since the path is based on the Show object not the episode , episodes only belong to one show. or am I missing something ?

Comment: Lets say `songA->episodeX`, and `songA->episodeY`. Now it is not intended but possible for: `EpisodeX->Show1`, `EpisodeY->Swow2`. In your admin interface you will have a box where all songs will be available for every episode. So mistake is quite probable. Instead in your `Mp3` you could have a `ForeignKey` directly to `Show`. And in `Episode`.`ManyToMany`->`Mp3` with limited choices to those Mp3 wich Show is parent of current Episode. Check the documentation for limited choice fields: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to

Comment: I might be wrong about the `limit_choices` part. There seems to be no way to limit those choices correctly with this attribute. But either way I recommend you to have a ForeignKey to Show. It will be easier to query for objects.

Comment: Well After finally being able to get back to this to actually implement it I found it dosen't work. The reason is that instance.episode does not point to anything because instance referes only to the mp3 instance which does not get passed the episode it was added from. I don't know if it would work or not if I did tie an mp3 to a specific episode by adding the ForiegnKey to Show or not, but I think for what I'm doing I'll just begrudgingly stick with the standard Y\M\D folder name.